# Chrome extension to read the JS console logs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

imaging googling for the words 'developing google chrome extension to read JS console logs'

therefore am asking the question here.

I need to write an extension to read the JS console logs. I have an app and I need to read the logs to manipulate it so that I can show them in the manner I want.

But reading several docs, e.g. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/devtools/
I do not find how to 'read' the logs via an API and parse them.

I am not interesting in log using console.log rather read those logs and show them in a 'pretty' way in my extension.

any hints?

Comment: Actually, you want to intercept the `console.logs` messages before they are written to the console and transform them? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript

Comment: yes, that is right. I want to transform them and display them in my extensions UI, where I will have custom filters specific to my 'app/website'. this is for internal use only

Comment: As such, I really think this is a SO question but it already answered by the linked QA.